# Graph in R not shown in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, chromebook

I'm trying to create a simple plot using ggplot. R was installed using conda through the build-in Linux beta terminal came with Pixelbook, my R version 3.5.1. Code worked fine on Mac and Ubuntu, and on Pixelbook all libraries were loaded fine. Terminal R and Jupyter notebook initiated from the same virtual environment can successfully render graphs using rkernel.

code

```
ggplot(df, aes(idiom_lang, exp_resp.rt, color = phrase_condition))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  ylab('Reaction time')+
  facet_wrap(~nat_LAN)
```

error

```
Error in dev.control(displaylist = "enable") : dev.control() called without an open graphics device
```

Help please!

Comment: This requires a [mcve] to become on-topic. Just to make sure, please also take the [tour] and read [ask] if you haven't already.

Comment: are you using RStudio Desktop or RStudio Server? And are you running it in ChromeOS or in Linux?

Comment: I installed R desktop in Debian Linux, I was able to get it to work after reinstalling rstudio but after a couple days of use, same problem returned..